# Generate cache file with php?

Tags: php, mysql, caching

I'm using http://datatables.net/examples/ for easy control table. I'm generating table with more than 30,000 records from a MySQL table, and loading is very slow. I want to cache this table and think that everything will go faster. I used `ob_get_contents()` but cache file size was 26MB. How can I create cache file to make everything go faster?

Comment: You're going about this the wrong way. You should just load what you need on demand. There's no reason to have 30k rows of data at a time. http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/ajax.html

Comment: As @MetalFrog has said, 30k rows on one page would be insane. I'd consider some form of pagination or filtering.

Comment: Also try see how long the query for retrieving 30k rows actually takes. My guess is that the javascript processing and html rendering is what actually takes time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the output buffer size is 26MB then the problem is that it's just taking a long time for your browser to download the page after the server generates it. You should either limit the number of rows that are returned, or use a pagination system.

For pagination, I'd do something like this:

Have a URL like: `http://website.com/script.php?start=3000`

and then do something like

```
$start = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['start']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table LIMIT $start, 100";
```

You'd then want to print out a URL on the page that links to the next page:

```
$nextpage = $start + 100;
echo "<a href='/script.php?start=$nextpage'>Next Page</a>";
```